# webservice with thread on glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: multithreading, spring, glassfish

i have a webapp written with spring 3 and struts 2 that is hosted on a glassfish server. In this app i have two webservices that need to do some background work without delaying the accessed method response.

So, now i use a spring bean that uses an instance of `org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor` and from there i run my new thread.

Is this the correct/best practice approach in context of using this app on glassfish? or should find another method of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's discouraged to create your own threads because the app server is meant to be in charge. See the answers to [Why is spawning threads in Java EE container discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533783/why-spawning-threads-in-j2ee-container-is-discouraged)

However in practice, especially if it's the only application on there, you might be OK, especially if you use a fixed thread pool. Be sure all the threads are gone when you undeploy the app. (I expect Spring classes will handle disposal on undeploy / shutdown correctly, if you declare them within the Spring container).

Comment: yes, this is my only app running on that server. Thanks for link.

Comment: Note that there is now a sanctioned way to create threads in web containers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212255/java-ee-specification-and-multi-threading/19404307#19404307