# Are there cases where it's okay to multithread on a application server?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee

Threading in an application server is normally a big taboo. However, it seems quite common to use libraries that use threads on the server (spymemcached for example use a dedicated thread).
Is there an acceptable way of threading on the server or are these libraries just "breaking the rules" for the sake of functionality?

I've always wondered about this but never found an answer better than "don't worry about it".

Comment: I think it's a tabu because it's error-prone. So, it's better to avoid it, if possible, since the application server is already implicitly multithreading (resource usage is good, so there's no need to improve it with multithreading). Anyway, if it's actually needed, because you want some operations to be parallel, or because you're using a library that is agnostic to the threading of the server, then there's actually nothing wrong, as long as you are aware of the potential threading issues.

Comment: My app server had to make additional service calls, compute all results, and then take some action. I threaded those calls to make them concurrently.

Comment: This shouldn't be [on hold], but simply flagged as duplicate. There are already many questions an the topic, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212255/java-ee-specification-and-multi-threading/3212316#3212316

Comment: Java EE 7 has support for that ("Concurrency Utilities for Java EE 1.0", so on the GlassFish v4 you can use it.