# Options for @Asynchronous like feature in Weblogic 11g?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic11g, java-ee-5

Options for `@Asynchronous`-like feature in Weblogic 11g (apart from JMS of course)? Use `Executor` service and spawn unmanaged threads?

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate of [Custom Thread on Weblogic Server 11g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516540/custom-thread-on-weblogic-server-11g) but it looks like it didn't pass review for some reason. In any event you will find your answer there. I've used the CommonJ WorkManager approach in the past.

Comment: You are right. Work Manager API is a weblogic specific way of managing threads which are under container control

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533783/why-spawning-threads-in-java-ee-container-is-discouraged).

If you have to stick with Java EE 5, you might want to look for external scheduling APIs, e.g. [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation).

Comment: Weblogic offers CommonJ work manager and timer API. Not sure why i would use quartz? Am i missing something?

Comment: @Abhishek: Of course you can use other frameworks than Quartz, it's just something we used successfully in our applications for a similar purpose. So if this is available in WebLogic, then use that. (Or better try to convince upgrading to a newer version and be able to use a newer Java EE if possible.) In either case, don't do thread handling yourself in the container.

Comment: Yes. Java EE 6 would be great.. Weblogic 12.1.3 supports some Java EE 7 apis as well. Lets see if I can shoot for it