# Right way to create threads in a J2EE webapp - PMD DoNotUseThreads violation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, pmd

I am trying to create a task inside my webapp, which runs in a thread of it's own. It is a monitoring task that should run for the entire duration of the application. For this purpose, I have created a class that looks like:

```
public class MonitoringTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // perform monitoring task action
    }
}
```

However, I get the "PMD.DoNotUseThreads" error mentioned [here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/j2ee.html). If creating threads by implementing Runnable is not the recommended way in a J2EE webapp, what is?

Comment: Which version of the J2EE/JEE spec are you using? Latest versions support container managed `Executor`s (read thread pools). In older versions, you have to live with the warning.

Comment: further reading as this has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212255/java-ee-specification-and-multi-threading

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos - I am not really sure about the version of the spec. I think the PMD ruleset is common across the company. Thanks for the pointer to the ManagedExecutorService though, did not know about the new Concurrent Utils.

Answer (score 1):

A java job (e.g. quartz) can be used to monitor after specified interval. This will ensure that the thread is not running forever. Can be used in J2EE environment.