# Is it safe to use ScheduledExecutorService in libraries?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am building a Java library that needs to perform a periodic check on some url.

This library will be used by users in their own applications.

The library uses a `ScheduledExecutorService` that performs this check every 3 minutes...

My question is, can this thread created by my library interfere with the application's threads? Is my approach safe?

Comment: I think using it in the library is just like using it in your application. And so it should be safe I guess.

Comment: It depends. Depends on how you construct the `ScheduledExecutorService`. If you are in a JEE environment you shouldn't be creating your own threads but rather use the JEE server managed `ExecutorService`. So it depends on how and where your library is being used it it safe or not.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Maybe.

Problem: When you're not using a own `ScheduledExecutorService`, then it's possible, that the `ScheduledExecutorService` of the spring-project is "too small". In other words: The poolsize is not enough.

But when you create a own `ScheduledExecutorService` in your libary which are used only by you, than you should be safe.

#### Edit

It's also problematic in Java EE projects, since they don't allow to create threads.
See [Java EE specification and multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212255/java-ee-specification-and-multi-threading) for details.

Thanks @M. Deinum

Comment: It depends on the use-case and environment that the library is being used in. In a JEE environment, you shouldn't be creating your own threads. Which is what happens when you use the `ScheduledExecutorService`, although indirectly.

Comment: The ScheduledExecutorService would only be calling a URL to populate a variable only used internally by the library. The application using the library would only not "see" that variable.
Would that make things any better? Or still not fully safe to use it?